# Embed YouTube Video with No Ads

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm embedding YouTube videos in a widget (http://www.betterdonatebutton.com) to help non-profits raise money. Unfortunately, some of them are not technically inclined enough to turn off ads that display over their videos.

How do I embed a YouTube video and specify that I prefer no ads to be displayed?

Comment: If they have ads enabled on the videos they uploaded/own, I'm fairly sure you can't embed their video without showing "their" ads.

Comment: Perhaps an alternate solution should be found, like if we uploaded the video for them into our website YouTube account.

Comment: This doesn't answer the ad question, but to remove suggested videos at the end, simply add ```?rel=0``` at the end of the src in the iframe. For example: ```src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/hello8675309?rel=0"```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Whether ads are shown on a video is up to the content owner of that video. It's not something that the embedder can control.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en)

If you had permission from the content owners of the videos to upload copies in your own account, and then ensured that your account was set up with monetization turned off, then that would prevent ads from showing during playback. It's up to you to work out that arrangement/permission with the original videos' owners, of course.

(It's also worth pointing out that if your goal is to help non-profits raise money, then allowing them to monetize their video playbacks is in line with that goal...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We talked the nonprofits into letting us upload their video into our channel.

Comment: Concerning helping them raise money, the ads actually work against them, since we're trying to get people to donate and need to look professional and trustworthy. But that is a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

If you play the video as a playlist and then single out that video you can get it without ads.  Here is what I have done: `https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEO_ID&autoplay=1&rel=0`

Comment: @Kevin, I am still getting ads when I tried in this way also "https://www.youtube.com/v/txqiwrbYGrs?playlist=txqiwrbYGrs&autoplay=1&rel=0" Please let me known if I did any wrong...

Comment: @HarshaVardhan, did you find a working method? I, too, tried `<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEO_ID&autoplay=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`, but ads are showing. Maybe this is an old method that no longer works?

Answer (score 6):

I'd just like to add, and please correct me if I'm wrong, that when I embed the HTML5 version of the videos, it doesn't play ads on top.

Not sure if this will ever change. They're probably just trying to work out the best way to show ads on the HTML5 player.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great point. Unfortunately, HTML5 is only supported in about half of the browsers that we support.

Answer (score 4):

From the YouTube help:

> You will automatically be opted into showing ads on embedded videos if
>   you've associated your YouTube and AdSense accounts and have enabled
>   your videos for embedding.
>
> If you don't want to show overlay ads on your embedded videos, you can
>   opt your videos out of showing overlay ads, though this will also
>   disable overlay ads on your videos on YouTube.com. You may also
>   disable your videos for embedding.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en

Another technical solution could be to use a custom video player, and streamline the youtube video with that one. Have not tried but guess that the ads cannot be displayed in a custom player. However, [could be forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214632/is-it-legal-to-use-a-youtube-video-in-a-custom-player).

Comment: could you please tell how to do this practically.

Answer (score -2):

For whom can help, nowadays in 2018, youtube have options for this:

(Example in Catalan, sorry :)

[image]

Translation of the 3 arrows : "Share" - "Embed" - "Show suggested videos when the video is finished"

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please write the translation below the image?

Comment: Done. added translations, sorry

Comment: Suggested videos are not the same things as ads.