# YouTube Ads in Embedded Videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I tried to find out about Ads on YouTube embedded videos, but didn't get any solution.

Actually, I am embedding videos from my multiple YouTube channels (we have different channels for different categories) to my website. But, I am not able to see any ads on my videos on my website. I am using YouTube Data API v3 to fetch videos on my website.

Do I have to manage Ads from YouTube Data API?

OR

I have to manage Ads from my different YouTube channels or my YouTube account?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before. These 2 links might help you

[Embed YouTube Video with No Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981310/embed-youtube-video-with-no-ads)

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en

Comment: Earlier, I went through second link. But, my question is, "Can we manage ads from YouTube Data API v3 or we have to manage them from our YouTube account?".

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage ads from your youtube user account, it's not allowed to manage them from the page where they're embedded

> Prohibitions:
>
> .7. modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the YouTube player;

from the youtube documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms