# is it possible to replace Youtube's Iframe Video Ads

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, embed, youtube-iframe-api

is it possible to replace Youtube's embedded Video's Ads with my own video ads. 
maybe using a video player to do that but how can i do?
for example. someone is embedding youtube videos somewhere else. he wants to show some video ads on those videos. how can he do that?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is *impossible*. It is, however, illegal to do so. When using the YouTube Data API or the JS API you agree to their [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms), which explicitly state that you may not alter or remove in-player ads of embedded videos (section II, paragraph 7).

Answer (score 0):

## Is it possible to replace Youtube's embedded Video's ads with my own video ads?

If you own the video the answer is YES, but if it's own by someone, the answer is NO. Only the owner/author of the video have rights to the ads of these video.

For more information, you can check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981310/embed-youtube-video-with-no-ads). It might give you an idea about your problem.

Also from the [YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en), it is stated here that:

> You will automatically be opted into showing ads on embedded videos if
> you've associated your YouTube and AdSense accounts and have enabled
> your videos for embedding.  Note that embedded videos will honor the
> same ad enablement settings as videos on youtube.com.
>
> If you don't want to show ads on your embedded videos, there is no way
> to directly disable ads on just embedded videos, however, you may
> disable your videos for embedding altogether.

Comment: Edit: i meant to say Pre roll ads and pre roll static ads. i saw some site does

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tune.pk sorry

Comment: me neither. but just open a video without adblocker. you will see a ad apears before the video plays. and after video ends