# Embed YouTube Video as Background with No Ads

Tags: javascript, css, html, youtube, html5-video

I know its said in [Embed YouTube Video with No Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981310/embed-youtube-video-with-no-ads) that it is up to the content owner if ads are shown or not.

However, I think there must be a workaround if you use a YouTube video as background in HTML5.

I discovered this website http://www.lifealignmentor.com/ after checking the source code I realized its using this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZfN87gSjvI). The video on YouTube has ads enabled. However on the website http://www.lifealignmentor.com/ I never saw the ads.

So is the website using a forbidden hack or is there actually a way to embed a YouTube video as background without seeing the ads?

I don't know if it helps, but I also found that the website is using the [Onetone MageeWP Theme](https://mageewp.com/wordpress-themes/).